# What will happen to regular web part pages with the modern layout in SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-document-library

With all going on in the o365 environment I´ve offered some thought to how the transition from todays environment to the new one would happen, and some questions was raised.

1. Does anyone know what will happen to already developed scripts running in script editor webparts in regular web part pages? Will these continue to work as normal and won´t be touched?
2. With the new layout it looks like the master page is on it´s way out. Does anyone have any info regarding this? What about people who have placed scripts in the master page to make it effect the whole site collection?

Thanks for any answers regarding these questions. I feel like we need to have a discussion around this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s been some months since I first asked this question. Jeff Teper stepped up and was answering some questions on Twitter a couple of days ago and stated that there were no plans to "turn off" the classic pages.

That means that we will be able to continue to use the classic pages in the future aswell in addition to the modern experience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very early to say, but below are my thoughts.

Regarding point#1 - Ideally the scripts running in script editor webpart should work as it is...one thing is for sure, scripts which we write in webpart are nothing but sort of javascript/jquery code which modern browser understands... If it's syntax is correct and calls are made correctly it will execute and modify DOM elements as it is..

Regarding point#2 - The concept of master page is very old(basically it is being used in other technologies with different name). They cannot eliminate master page completely, there will be a alternate way to add common html code like header and footer which will be shared across whole sites....it is not just about script it is about usability and maintenance which master page take cares of....Header and Footer of all the pages would be mostly same and we don't need to go to each page to modify/add if something needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hope this is the case aswell.